Why do below two integrals hold
I am reading a book where it suggests

$$\dot{I} = \lambda \dot{P} - v I$$
$$I(T) = \int_0^T \lambda\dot{P}(t) e^{-v(T-t)} dt$$

I figured this equation out:
\begin{align*}
   \mu(t) &= e^{\int (-\nu) \, dt} \\
   &= e^{-\nu t}
   \end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
   e^{-\nu t} \dot{I} + \nu e^{-\nu t} I = \lambda e^{-\nu t} \dot{P}
   \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
   \frac{d}{dt} (e^{-\nu t} I) = \lambda e^{-\nu t} \dot{P}
   \end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
   \int \frac{d}{dt} (e^{-\nu t} I) \, dt &= \lambda \int e^{-\nu t} \dot{P} \, dt \\
   e^{-\nu t} I &= \lambda \int e^{-\nu t} \dot{P} \, dt + C
   \end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
   I(t) = e^{\nu t} \left( \lambda \int e^{-\nu t} \dot{P} \, dt + C \right)
   \end{equation*}
later it suggests

Define $C(T) = - \int_0^T P(t)\dot{I}(t) dt$. Integrating this
equation by part, we obtain
\begin{align} C(T) &= -P(T) I(T) + \int_0^T \dot{P}(t) I(t) dt \\
      &= -P(T)I(T) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \int \int_0^T \dot{P}(t_1) \dot{P}(t_2) e^{-v |t_1-t_2|} d t_1 d t_2 
\end{align}

Here I can follow the first step $C(T) = -P(T) I(T) + \int_0^T \dot{P}(t) I(t) dt $, but not the second step.
I'd appreciate if someone can kindly explain the derivation.

How do you solve $\dot I(t) + vI(t) = g(t)$?

@TedShifrin thanks for the hint. I added some edits. i can figure out the first equation now, but not the second one

Substitute $I$ inside the integral within the expression for $C$ by its own integration representation derived beforehand.

Presumably, you've omitted the initial value $I(0)=0$. Limtis of integration are missing in that final integral. You should be able to get  $$\int_0^T \dot P(t)\int_0^t \lambda\dot P(u)e^{-v(t-u)},du,dt.$$ I believe they're trying to use symmetry to turn this into an integral over $[0,T]\times [0,T]$.
